# What is the best way to implement a method that does some pretty heavy operations like updating a database, retrieving from a database?

Tags: c#, performance

I have a piece of code about few hundread lines, this code is inside a while loop which gets executed each time for about 1000 records.

I want to move this code out of the while loop and place it in a seperate method , what is the best way improve the performance of the application

Implementing the code as a static method, or a non static method

Note: The code contains objects like Datasets, Datareaders, and data adapters whic

Comment: Your question is very vaque. You will have to show us some code, because we will not be able to help you right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is **almost** no difference between calling a static method and calling an instance method. There is a slight difference since one is doing CLR `call` and the other doing `virtual call` and CLR has to navigate the types to find the implementation but that is **really negligible**.

**Your main concern here must be readability when you have a 1000-line code rather than performance.** Whatever you do, calling your database will be the slowest part of your code so **instead focus on refactoring**.

Answer (score 1):

Static or non-static has no impact on performance in your case.

Comment: It does make a difference. Virtual calls are not free. But it's probably negligible if your code does "pretty heavy operations".

Comment: Please explain the difference. I can only think about differences that aren't of any practical interest, because they are so small.

Comment: yes, the differences are indeed small. I was commenting on an older version of your answer that didn't have the "in your case" in the end. As a general statement, it was wrong. The small differences include the need to pass `this` and possible lookups into vtables. Very small and probably negligible.

Comment: @Martinho: Thanks for your clarification. I updated my answer, because that was really what I meant from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the code into the `DoWork` method of a `BackgroundWorker`. This way, your code can run in a background thread, give periodic progress updates to the main UI thread, and let the UI thread know when the operations are completed by invoking the `WorkerCompleted` event.